# MapR oozie sqoop error; Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Tags: sqoop, oozie, mapr

I'm repeatedly getting this error when I submit a sqoop job using oozie on MapR. Details below. I even copied the mysql jar file to the share/lib/sqoop directory, with no result. Could you please help?

**Command:**

```
/opt/mapr/oozie/oozie-4.0.1/bin/oozie job -oozie=http://OOZIE_URL:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

**Error**

```
2015-06-18 01:54:05,818 WARN SqoopActionExecutor:542 - SERVER[data-sci1] USER[mapr] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[sqoop-orders-wf] JOB[0000024-150616000730465-oozie-mapr-W] ACTION[0000024-150616000730465-oozie-mapr-W@sqoop-orders-node] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]
```

**MaprFS:**

```
/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
```

**job.properties:**

```
nameNode=maprfs:/// jobTracker=YARN_RESOURCE_MANAGER:8032 queueName=default

oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=maprfs:/oozie/data/sqoop/orders

mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
```

**workflow.xml:**

```
<start to="sqoop-orders-node"/>
 <action name="sqoop-orders-node">
     <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
         <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
         <configuration>
             <property>
                 <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                 <value>${queueName}</value>
             </property>
         </configuration>
         <arg>import</arg>
         <arg>--hbase-create-table</arg>
         <arg>--hbase-table</arg>
         <arg>orders</arg>
         <arg>--column-family</arg>
         <arg>d</arg>
         <arg>--username</arg>
         <arg>USERNAME</arg>
         <arg>--password</arg>
         <arg>PASSWORD</arg>
         <arg>--connect</arg>
         <arg>"jdbc:mysql://HOST?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round"</arg>
         <arg>--query</arg>
         <arg>--split-by</arg>
         <arg>o.OrderId</arg>
         <arg>--hbase-row-key</arg>
         <arg>rowkey</arg>
         <arg>-m</arg>
         <arg>8</arg>
         <arg>--verbose</arg>
         <arg>--query</arg>
         <arg>select o.OrderId as rowkey, o.OrderId as orderId from orders WHERE \$CONDITIONS</arg>
     </sqoop>
     <ok to="end"/>
     <error to="fail"/>
 </action>
 <kill name="fail">
     <message>Sqoop free form failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
 </kill>
 <end name="end"/>
```

Comment: You have to check logs of a process running your Main class to see an actual error